# Verold Publisher 3ds max not uploading

Tags: verold

Suddenly stopped working. Gets as far as message which says "Published a model to Verold, yay!... etc" but when clicked to view, returns a 404 error on the webpage. have reinstalled - no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Verold fixed it quite quickly :)